# Subgroups of torsion abelian groups

Tags: abelian-groups

I want to know any  subgroups of the infinite direct sum of the abelian group $\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}$ where $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: There's a lot of them....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.